# accumulative multiplication between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df and I would like to do an accumulative multiplication between two columns, I will leave a code and example and another example that I managed to do in excel, but I would need to do it in python

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "ValDate":["2008-04-07", "2008-04-08", "2008-04-09", "2008-04-10", "2008-04-11","2008-04-14","2008-04-15"], 
        "TradingDesk":["LOTUS", "LOTUS", "LOTUS", "LOTUS", "LOTUS", "LOTUS", "LOTUS"], 
        "COTA": [1.000000,1.000383,1.000865,1.001225,1.001600,1.001985,1.002372]
    })

df['Pct Change'] = df['COTA'].pct_change()



    ValDate TradingDesk COTA    Pct Change
0   2008-04-07  LOTUS   1.000000    NaN
1   2008-04-08  LOTUS   1.000383    0.000383
2   2008-04-09  LOTUS   1.000865    0.000482
3   2008-04-10  LOTUS   1.001225    0.000360
4   2008-04-11  LOTUS   1.001600    0.000375
5   2008-04-14  LOTUS   1.001985    0.000384
6   2008-04-15  LOTUS   1.002372    0.000386
```

I would like to do the cumulative multiplication between the 'Pct Change' and 'COTA' columns so that I would take the first available Pct Change value and multiply it by the "COTA" on the bottom row

example in excel

in the first row of the "Accumulative" column the value would be the same as that of the "Pct Change" column

[image]

The second line would be the account of the first value of the "accumulative" column multiplied by the value of the following day or the bottom line of the "pct change" column adding the value below the "accumulative" column and using this value to calculate from the next line

[image]

I can do it only in excel but I needed a solution for python

Comment: your computation looks equivalent to `COTA-1`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html):

```
df['cumprod'] = df['Pct Change'].add(1).cumprod().sub(1)
```

output:

```
      ValDate TradingDesk      COTA  Pct Change   cumprod
0  2008-04-07       LOTUS  1.000000         NaN       NaN
1  2008-04-08       LOTUS  1.000383    0.000383  0.000383
2  2008-04-09       LOTUS  1.000865    0.000482  0.000865
3  2008-04-10       LOTUS  1.001225    0.000360  0.001225
4  2008-04-11       LOTUS  1.001600    0.000375  0.001600
5  2008-04-14       LOTUS  1.001985    0.000384  0.001985
6  2008-04-15       LOTUS  1.002372    0.000386  0.002372
```